# Finding the supremum and the infimum of given set as follows.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, order-theory

Find the supremum and the infimum of
\begin{equation*}
A = \left\{\left(-\frac{1}{m}, \frac{1}{n}\right): m,n \in \Bbb N\right\}
\end{equation*}
on the set $X = 2^{\Bbb R}$ (the set of all subset of $\Bbb R$) which is partially ordered by inclusion. (Note: all element in $A$ is an open interval).

**Definition.** Let $S$ be a non-empty set. A set $X=2^S$ (the set of all subset of $S$) with partially ordered inclusion:
\begin{equation*}
A \le B \iff A \subseteq B, \quad \forall A,B \in X.
\end{equation*}

**Attempt:**
I claim that $\sup A = (-1,1)$ and $\inf A$ doesn't exist. Firstly, we'll show that $\sup A = (-1,1)$. Notice that for all $m,n \in \Bbb N$, we have $-1 \le -\frac{1}{m} < 0$ and $0 < \frac{1}{n} \le 1$.
Hence, $\left(-\frac{1}{m}, \frac{1}{n}\right) \subseteq (-1,1)$. By definition above, we have $\left(-\frac{1}{m}, \frac{1}{n}\right) \le (-1,1)$.
Therefore, $(-1,1)$ is an upper bound of $A$. Now, let $(a,b) \in X$ be another upper bound of $A$. Then,
\begin{equation*}
\left(-\frac{1}{m}, \frac{1}{n}\right) \le (a,b) \quad \forall m,n \in \Bbb N \iff \left(-\frac{1}{m}, \frac{1}{n}\right) \subseteq (a,b), \forall m,n \in \Bbb N. \qquad (\star)
\end{equation*}
Now, claim that $a \le -1$ and $1 \le b$. Suppose that $a > -1$ and $b < 1$. Then, $(a,b) \subseteq (-1,1)$, and so $(a,b) \le (-1,1)$. This contradicts $(\star)$. Hence, $a \le -1$ and $1 \le b$. Therefore,
\begin{equation*}
(-1,1) \subseteq (a,b) \iff (-1,1) \le (a,b).
\end{equation*}
Thus, $(-1,1)$ is the least upper bound of $A$. Hence, $\sup A = (-1,1)$.

Now, suppose that $\inf A$ exists, namely, $(a,b)$. Then,
\begin{equation*}
(a,b) \le \left(-\frac{1}{m}, \frac{1}{n}\right), \forall m,n \in \Bbb N \iff (a,b) \subseteq \left(-\frac{1}{m}, \frac{1}{n}\right), \forall m,n \in \Bbb N.
\end{equation*}
That means that $-\frac{1}{m} \le a < 0$ and $0 < b \le \frac{1}{n}$, for all $m,n \in \Bbb N$. So, the value of $a$ and $b$ are depending on the value of $m$ and $n$, respectively, i.e., $(a,b)$ is not unique. This contradicts the fact that the infimum of a set (if exists) is unique.
Thus, $\inf A$ doesn't exist.

Does the above proof correct?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Why downvote? ${}$

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I'm not used to the terms supremum and infimum being used on a partially ordered set. Maybe that's confusing others too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you want to find the infimum and supremum   ***in*** $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$, ***not in*** $A$, so the infimum does exist and is $\{0\}$, because $\{0\}$ and $\varnothing$ are the only sets which are subsets of all elements of $A$[Since  $\bigcap A=\{0\}$]. The supremum is $(-1,1)$ because:  it’s an upper bound, and if $M$ is an upper bound then $(-1,1)$ must be a subset of $M$ since $(-1,1)\in A$.

Comment: So, basically, the infimum of $A$ is the singleton $\{0\}$, right?

Comment: @krewlpt Right.

Comment: Although all  element of $A$ are of the form open interval, does the singleton like $\{0\}$ allowed for being the infimum?

Comment: And the question is asking for the supremum and supremum of $A$, not $X$.

Comment: Can I write the singleton $\{0\}$ as $(0,0)$ ?

Comment: @krewlpt It’s asking for the supremum **of** $A$ **in** $X$. The interval $(0,0)$ is empty.

Comment: @krewlpt So no you can’t write it like that. Does that make sense? There is no problem with the Infimum being a singleton. Why should there be? Please check for yourself using the definitions.

Comment: Aaah I see. Because the definition of $A$ and of the inclusion, the infimum is $\0\}$. Thanks sir.